# The Eclipse IDE is able to generate the javacard cap file but in command line I am encountering this error

Tags: java, eclipse, javacard, cap

The below error compelled me to dig into the build process of a cap file in the command line without using the IDE. So now, I can build a cap file from the command line using java/javac series of commands. But I have this one applet which successfully created a cap file if built via eclipse IDE but I am encountering an error when i try to build in the command line. I am also having same error when I tried in a correctly setup gradle build settings/environment. This is the error:

```
[ant:convert] [ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
[ant:convert]
[ant:convert]
[ant:convert] warning: You did not supply export file for the previous minor version of the package
[ant:convert] [ INFO: ] conversion completed with 1 errors and 1 warnings.
[ant:convert] error: Class org/dx/tools/TestApplet, specified in -applet option, is abstract.
```

Take note, this is a working and tested applet in combination with other applets that uses this one. And this builds in the eclipse IDE.

Also I am able to generate the `.class` file. The problem is during the convertion  of the class file to `cap` file.

Here is how it look like:

```
package org.dx.tools;

import org.globalplatform.GPSystem;
import org.globalplatform.SecureChannel;

import javacardx.apdu.ExtendedLength;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.APDUException;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.AppletEvent;    

public abstract class TestApplet extends Applet implements AppletEvent, 
    ExtendedLength {
  ...
}
```

This `.cap` is one among five others. The others are not abstract, but inherits from this one. Since it build in eclipse IDE, I can actually build the other cap files by taking the output of the IDE had produce. First, I `jar` the classes since as I said I can create the classes and feed to `java` conversion command to build the other caps, and I also use the `TestApplet.exp` that the IDE generated.

**UPDATES: 2019/11/17**
[Here](https://gist.github.com/8ee3994375553d34312ee9b14182c88d) is the actual `java` command options that is able to build from `.class` to `.cap`. I took this as exactly from the Eclipse IDE conversion log.

If an answer can confirm this is a current gradle limitation then I will accept this answer. If answer can show what is the correct gradle settings to make it work then I will accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I followed the exact `java` conversion invocation parameters emitted by Windows eclipse IDE when converting the `.class` to `.cap` and type this very same exact command in a linux machine and it was able to convert the `.class` to `.cap`. Staying away for a while from gradle magic for the mean time until somebody here can comment on whats happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by removing the `applet {}` block in `build.gradle`. As the particular cap being built is an abstract class, it does not have an applet aid.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely due to linking to a newer or older version of a library, while targeting a different Java Card version during your build process. Note that the converter creates pre-linked code, so it expects to link against the correct versions.

This is different from Java SE, where the classes can be linked at runtime and the *location* of methods and fields doesn't matter, as they are created during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am keeping this question open, and the answer that I will accept is an answer that shows the proper gradle settings that can convert the `TestApplet` class above to a `.cap` (or an `.exp` would be enough). I will also accept an answer that can confirm that this is a current limitation in gradle. I just added the actual `java` command that was able to convert the `.class` to `.cap` for reference.

Comment: That's fair I suppose. Java Card is a small community, you might (have to) consider fixing it yourself...